# Similar shapes painted differently

Tags: android, android-styles

I do not understand why there is such difference in result when code is almost the same.

[image]

Both buttons are generated using the same code:

```
int resId = (tile.getFormula() == null) ? R.layout.template_puzzle_result : R.layout.template_puzzle_formula;
AppCompatButton button = (AppCompatButton) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(resId, puzzleGrid, false);
    colorsNormal = ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.tile_normal));
button.setSupportBackgroundTintList(colorsNormal);
```

They are standard buttons stored in `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`. The only difference is a style property.

```
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    style="@style/PuzzleTileResult"
/>
```

Styles are same except a `background` property. There is strange warning icon that I do not understand.

[image]

The left button is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >    
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <stroke
        android:width="30px"
        android:color="@color/green_215" />    
</shape>
```

The right button is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >    
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3px"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent" />    
</shape>
```

Colors:

```
<color name="tile_normal">#ffee00</color> - yellow
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color> - blue
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color> - pink
```

I would expect

- left button to be 30px thick green border and yellow interior
- right button to be 3px thick pink border and yellow interior

But it does not behave consistently - left button takes interior color from XML and right from code. And the left one has surrounding painted with the code color while the right one does not. Why?

Comment: your solid color is colorPrimary while your expect is yellow interior

Comment: I override it with button.setSupportBackgroundTintList(R.color.tile_normal)

Comment: oh, yes. what's your tintmode?

Comment: Default because I have not specified any concrete value.

Comment: I can't understand the left is rectangle while your shape is oval. tint is blending with background, so different background color will lead to different show [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/R.attr.html#backgroundTintMode). I can't find the default tintmode. try to set a tintmode for AppCompatButton? Such as screen?

Comment: I switched to design mode in Android studio and both tiles are oval with colors as defined in XML. So it must be related to tinting. I use it as the only way how to specify background color. Specifying colorPrimary requires API 21.

Comment: t tints all your color to yellow , so you get a yellow circle without stroke.

Comment: Studio warns me that backgroundTintMode is in API 21 while I use 17. I tested in anyway (Nexus 5x has Android 6) but there was no effect manipulating this attribute.

Comment: When I disable setting BG tint list it works correctly. But I need to change background color dynamically from a code.